# tools for generating wiki format article (mark up code)

Tags: wiki

when creating spreadsheets in wiki, is there any tools provides converting spreadsheets into mark up codes? So make it edit in GUI. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [FCKeditor](http://mediawiki.fckeditor.net/) which can automatically generate wiki mark up code, and also provide WYSIWYG.

FCKeditor replaced by [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo).